# Limit as $x\to \infty$ of $3(x^a) - 2(x^a)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm not sure what this limit should equal. Same goes for the equation where $a$ is equal to $1$. I want to say that it should equal the difference of the multipliers (1), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is that? It is a bit strange since $3(x^a) - 2(x^a)=x^a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$3x^a-2x^a=x^a$$

then we need to consider the following cases

- $a>0$
- $a=0$
- $a<0$